# Datetype conversion from dd-mmm-yyyy

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion, case

Table is patient, date type is formatted dd-mon-yyyy so today would be 25-jan-2013. 
I'm trying to compare a date of birth to determine someone's age group. Currently I have:

```
SELECT patient.last_name, CASE 
WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1988' THEN '1-25'
WHEN  patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
WHEN  patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75'
ELSE '75+'
END
AS "Age Range"
FROM patient;
```

I get the correct age ranges But I'd like to not hard code them in. I.E do currentdate minus 25 years etc. The only problem is I can't figure out how to convert my date time to allow for comparisons. I'd like to use mm-dd-yyyy I feel like this should be relatively easy but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Which type of `birthdate`?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Year()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) method?  You could simply subtract the current year from the birthday year to get a rough estimate.

Comment: I'm using ORACLE SQL developer the birthdate is a data_type date.

Comment: I haven't got access to any Oracle dbms, but in MS SQL the following should work:
    DATEADD(YEAR,-25,GETDATE())

Comment: ... In no RDBMS I am aware of, do date types _actually_ have a format, it's just something that's put on them at display time.  Which means that you shouldn't need to do _any_ formatting/parsing, if you're dealing with the current date (eg `patient.birthdate > current_date - 25 YEARS`).  Although, you're going to need to make sure that the 'current date' is the _start of the day_, as I believe date types on Oracle always have time attached.

Answer (score 1):

Use math:

```
SELECT patient.last_name, 
       CASE 
         WHEN patient.birthdate < SYSDATE-365 THEN '0-1'
         WHEN patient.birthdate < SYSDATE-9132 AND patient.birthdate > SYSDATE-365 THEN '1-25'
         WHEN patient.birthdate < SYSDATE-18263 AND patient.birthdate > SYSDATE-9132 THEN '25-50'
         WHEN patient.birthdate < SYSDATE-27394 AND patient.birthdate > SYSDATE-18263 THEN '50-75'
         ELSE '75+' 
       END AS "Age Range"
  FROM patient;
```

Of course, the mistake will be ~1 day because of leap year.

Comment: and almost forget, patient.birthdate have to be DATE

Comment: ... Why not avoid the error entirely, and do the math in years?  Every major RDBMS I'm aware of has relevant methods, and will behave 'properly' for that, and the math is a lot more intuitive (nobody just knows what 9132 days are).  Oh, `CASE` statements are _explicitly_ stated to execute in order, so you don't need the second condition (which should remove the errors your statement currently has).

Comment: I couldn't find a year function but I did it in months, here was my code. 'SELECT CASE
     WHEN (patient.birthdate  > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-300)) THEN '1-25' 
     WHEN (patient.birthdate  > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-600)) THEN '25-50'
     WHEN (patient.birthdate  > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-900)) THEN '50-75'
     ELSE '75+'  
     END AS Age_Range,  
     SUM(CASE WHEN patient.Sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,
     SUM(CASE WHEN patient.Sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M
FROM patient '

Answer (score 1):

Referring DATAADD I assume you use SQL Server. If the column is of date or datetime type the string format is only a rappresentation, you can use DATEADD with no problem.

But pay attention about your formula that is depending from the current date by using GETDATE(), in these case is possibile to have performance issues.

Comment: When I try to use DATEADD though I get this error. The format is WHEN patient.birthdate > DATEADD(yyyy, -25, patient.birthdate) THEN '1-25' and the error is get is this: ORA-00904: "DATEADD": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:

Comment: you wrote about DATEADD in your question... if you are using oracle  (by errmesg) take a look to: http://oracletuts.net/tutorials/how-to-calculate-difference-between-dates-in-oracle-sql/

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what RDBMS you're using.

If you're using MS SQL Server, you can use [`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to change this format to a datetime.

```
SELECT '12-mar-1980', CONVERT(datetime,'12-mar-1980',106)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql-Server;

```
SELECT patient.last_name,
    case    
    when datediff(year,patient.birthdate, getdate()) < 26 
               then '1-25'
    when datediff(year,patient.birthdate, getdate()) 
               between 26 and 50 then '26-50'
    when datediff(year,patient.birthdate, getdate()) < 76 
               then '51-75'
    else '75+' end [Age Range]
FROM patient
```

Comment: Given that `birthdate` is explicitly a date type, the conversion isn't necessary.  Oh, and I'd want to do the math on the current date, which may help the optimizer (although being SARGable isn't as important here, probably).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I see, conversion is a mistake actually. I had it while was testing with his given date.. Thanks for pointing out, I took that off.